# How to have a PHP conditional continue to check after a page has loaded

Tags: php, html

I have a search box that, after a user has hit the submit button while the results page is loading, I want to show some sort of progress indicator. This simplest I could find is this:

```
while ( $something == true ) {
  // Echo an extra dot, and flush the buffers
  // to ensure it gets displayed.
  echo ' .';
  flush();

  // Now sleep for 1 second and check again:
  sleep(1);
}
```

What I would imagine $something should be is simply whether or not the user has submitted the search form yet. The problem with that is that the above PHP code will not know that because the page has already finished loading.

How can I have that PHP execute only after the user has submitted the search form?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You'd need to use JavaScript for that (possibly also AJAX to interact with server side code)

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language, so it can not see what is going on in the browser. I will only respond to a request made by the browser. There are 2 ways to achieve what I think you are after.

**The ajax way:**
To have some sort of live feedback you will need a client side language, wich would be Javascript. I suggest you have a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), a javascript library, that is fairly easy to understand. More specificly you will be needing the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method and the [`.submit`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) event probabaly

**the PHP way:**
You could also have your form submit to the same php page the search form is on, and then detect wether the form has been submitted by checking if the form variables exist. Something like this:

```
if (array_key_exists('search', $_REQUEST) {
 // the form has been submitted
}
else  {
 // the form is not yet submitted
}
```

That is supposing the search box in your form has the name 'search'

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$('#submit').click(function(e)){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "path/to/php/action",
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data){
         while(data.action == 'waiting'){
             $('.somePageClass').html('<p>...</p>');
         }else{
             $('.somePageClass').html('your results');
         }
    });
});
```

something like that using ajax to call a php function, your php function will have to check whether your waiting or done and return data.action.

this may not be fully correct, but it's an attempt (at least in the right direction).

Comment: What would the URL parameter be? I don't have another page doing the scripting. It's just simple checking for the Submit button being clicked. What would the path be? I think that's what I'm a little lost on... Thanks!